# Flutter text will be cropped in flutter

Tags: flutter

The fixed height container wraps a text, the text text will be very long, but it will appear in the four line of the figure with a crop, what I want is if it is not fully displayed, it will not be displayed. How to fix it? The height of the container must be fixed.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(
          context,
          title: "Input list",
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Text(
            "The fixed height container wraps a text, the text text will be very long, but it will appear in the four line of the figure with a crop, what I want is if it is not fully displayed, it will not be displayed. How to fix it? The height of the container must be fixed",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
          ),
          width: double.maxFinite,
          color: Colors.greenAccent,
          height: 58,
        ),
       );
  }
```

[image]

The height of the container will be adaptive according to other widgets. Then I want to display more text without cropping the last line.

Comment: I want my fourth line of text not to appear at all

Answer (score 0):

Give your `Text` an `overflow` value, for example

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the overflowed text not to display, you can use `overflow: TextOverflow.clip`

Example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Text Overflow Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 100, // Limiting the height of the container
            color: Colors.blue,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text(
              'This is a long text that might overflow the container.' * 10,
              overflow: TextOverflow.clip, // or TextOverflow.clip
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try this code in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)

The `TextOverflow.clip` removes all the oveflowed text

`MY LONG TEXT` becomes `MY LONG T'

Output:

[image: Example]

Comment: If the height of the container in my code is going to change, I don't want to display three lines fixed, I want to display the most text, and the last line cannot be cropped

Comment: If that is the case, you can remove the maxLInes and update overflow as `TextOverflow.clip`

Comment: @ Sujan Gainju  This is not effective

Comment: It works as per your requirement of hiding the excessive text in the container. I have tried it in dartpad. Attached the output

Comment: If it appears normal on your phone, try changing the font size and you will find that there are still cuts

Comment: The "g" of the last word in your screenshot might has been captured